# Conditional Comments to target Windows Phone 7 Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows-phone-7, conditional-comments

## Problem

Conditional comments, such as

```
<!--[if IEMobile]>
    <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer Mobile.</p>
<![endif]-->
<![if !IEMobile]>
    <p>All other browsers</p>
<![endif]>
```

**don't work** on Windows Phone 7! Or, at least not on mine.

---

## Question

Does anyone know exactly how to use these comments, and had **tested them** before? Does IE 9 on WP7 even support this?

Answer (score 1):

Im sorry to say but the following used to work before Mango.

```
<!--[if IEMobile 7]>
    <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer Mobile.</p>
<![endif]-->
<![if !IEMobile 7]>
    <p>All other browsers</p>
<![endif]>
```

It looks like now you would have to use JAvaScript and check the UserAgent to see if Windows Phone OS 7 or Windows Phone OS 7.5 is listed...Only way

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this does not work. Did you test it?

Comment: Are you testing this on your decide or emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **gte** (in case it's seeing your phone as 7.5)

```
<!--[if gte IEMobile 7]>
<p>Welcome to Internet Explorer Mobile.</p>
<![endif]-->
<![if !IEMobile 7]>
<p>All other browsers</p>
<![endif]>
```